# How to format phone number without area code?

Tags: swift, swift3

I have phone number in following format.

```
+1-541-754-3010,
1-541-754-3010,
001-541-754-3010,
(541) 754-3010,
+91 5417543010,
+91-5417543010,
(+91)-5417543010
```

I want to remove area code from phone number which present in above format. Just need a phone number.
    So output should be like 
    5417543010

How can I do this is swift?

Answer (score 2):

As alternative to @TheTiger proposal you may use [PhoneNumberKit](https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit):

```
import PhoneNumberKit

let phoneNumberKit = PhoneNumberKit()

do {
    let phoneNumber = try phoneNumberKit.parse(yourNumberString)
    let national = phoneNumber.nationalNumber // that's what you ask for
}
catch let error {
    // handle error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Phone number formatting is not a quite easy task. Better to use this [Google libphonenumber](https://github.com/iziz/libPhoneNumber-iOS) library for phone number formatting which will even separate the area code from full phone number. Below is the quick look of the sample. **Library is available in swift too.**

```
NBPhoneNumberUtil *phoneUtil = [[NBPhoneNumberUtil alloc] init];
NSError *anError = nil;
NBPhoneNumber *myNumber = [phoneUtil parse:@"6766077303"
                          defaultRegion:@"AT" error:&anError];
if (anError == nil) {
   NSLog(@"isValidPhoneNumber ? [%@]", [phoneUtil isValidNumber:myNumber] ? @"YES":@"NO");

   // INTERNATIONAL : +43 676 6077303
   NSLog(@"INTERNATIONAL : %@", [phoneUtil format:myNumber
                                   numberFormat:NBEPhoneNumberFormatINTERNATIONAL
                                          error:&anError]);
   // NATIONAL      : 0676 6077303
   NSLog(@"NATIONAL      : %@", [phoneUtil format:myNumber
                                   numberFormat:NBEPhoneNumberFormatNATIONAL
                                          error:&anError]);

} else {
   NSLog(@"Error : %@", [anError localizedDescription]);
}

NSLog (@"extractCountryCode [%@]", [phoneUtil extractCountryCode:@"823213123123" nationalNumber:nil]);

NSString *nationalNumber = nil;
NSNumber *countryCode = [phoneUtil extractCountryCode:@"823213123123" nationalNumber:&nationalNumber];
```